# How to adjust DataGrid column with order numbers WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have such `DataGrid`

[image]

In order to get order number automatically I added in `DataGrid` method `LoadingRow` such way

`.xalm`

```xml
...
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=GridItems}"
            HorizontalGridLinesBrush="Gray"
            RowHeaderWidth="20"
            LoadingRow="Dg_main_configuration_LoadingRow"
            CanUserReorderColumns="False"
            CanUserDeleteRows="False"
            CanUserResizeRows="False"
            CanUserSortColumns="False"
            VerticalGridLinesBrush="LightGray"
            x:Name="Dg_main_configuration"
            CanUserResizeColumns="False"
            PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="Dg_main_configuration_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp"
            AlternatingRowBackground="LightYellow"
            CanUserAddRows="False"
            MinHeight="350"
            MaxHeight="350"
            Grid.Column="0"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False">
...
```

and in code

```cs
private void Dg_main_configuration_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.Header = (e.Row.GetIndex() + 1).ToString();
}
```

All is fine, but anyway I would like to adjust this row column

Problems is :

1. You can see in screenshot next to `Path to clip folder`(on the left) there is a cell with a rectangle at the right bottom, acctually it is kind of button(because I can click on it, but nothing changed), how to disable it, or set symbol like `#`?
2. Numbers `1, 2, 3, 4` horizontally not in the center, how to fix it?
3. And last is - you can see that there are a horizontal lines `DarkGray` that separates rows, but I don't know why numbers doesn't include this separate lines? I mean line starts after number column. How to include separate line in order numbers also?

Comment: How about an extra column instead of a row header?  Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15061668/1136211

Comment: Perhaps just `<DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"/>` with a large AlternationCount value set at the DataGrid.

Comment: @Clemens it looks like it is works. But how to set alignment (vertical and horizontal)?

Comment: By an appropriate CellTemplate in a DataGridTemplateColumn

Comment: @Clemens Can you take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/59933150/5709159

Comment: Just set HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment of a TextBlock in the CellTemplate to Center.

Comment: @Clemens but I don't have `TextBlock` I have a `DataGridTextColumn` and if I set it there like `VerticalAlignment ` , so with an alignment I also get that cell itself shifts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could display the row number in a column, for example using the approach mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15061668/7252182).

You could then use an `ElementStyle` to center the `TextBlock`:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, 
                        Converter={local:RowToIndexConverter}}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

For point 2 (and may also get you understand more about point 3). A DataGrid can have a [RowHeaderTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowheadertemplate?view=netframework-4.8) (or an even more general [RowHeaderStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowheaderstyle?view=netframework-4.8)) which would be applied to each row header value (that you set in code). Here is a [related question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41855770/wpf-datagrid-custom-row-header)

For point 1 (and also for point 2 for the default row header template, and point 3) I suggest you to look at Microsoft's default [DataGrid styles and templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/datagrid-styles-and-templates). You might need to set the entire DataGrid template to change the top-left part (or try having a resource with key {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}) - that is the DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, which supposedly is a button that would select all rows if the rows can be selected in the data grid.

For point 3, to set up the horizontal grid lines to a different color (e.g. matching row headers' separator) use [HorizontalGridLinesBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.datagrid.horizontalgridlinesbrush?view=netframework-4.8) property.