# How to set DataGridTextColumn vertically center (WPF)?

Tags: c#

I would like to numerate my rows in `DataGrid`, for this I am using such approach

https://stackoverflow.com/a/15061668/5709159

works nice, but number in cell not adjust center horizontally nor vertically.

Then I found such solution

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2729428/5709159

But this just center a number horizontally, but not vertically.

For vertical center I found such approach

https://stackoverflow.com/a/720824/5709159

but as wrote in comments

> The text was centered, but the cell width no longer matched up with its header

So, I get something like this

[image]

Do you see that there is double bottom line?

So, question is - how to center a number horizontally as well as vertically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could define an `ElementStyle`:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}, 
                        Converter={local:RowToIndexConverter}}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```